# Split phone number into area code and country code

Tags: angularjs, input, split

I'm working on angularJS:

I have an input field will can receive 10 numbers; and I store this number into a $scope.

In other part of myApp I will take this number and send it to a service. But before send, I have to split it number in two. The first 3 must be the area code, and the rest 7 must be the country code.

Comment: What's the format of it?

Comment: Will appreciate if you can share with us some of your code to give us some insight on what you are doing and what problem you are encountering.

Comment: The format is a string of numbers 0123456789, and I have to split it into 012 and 3456789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain Javascript:

```
var input = "0123456789";
var area = input.substring(0, 3);
var country = input.substring(3, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing a positive lookahead regular expression `(?=)` to make sure the input has 10 digits.

Then capture the digits into 2 separate groups by doing `(\d{x})` where x is the number of digits you want.

**Example:**

```js
"use strict";
let match = /(?=\d{10})(\d{3})(\d{7})/.exec("9994567890");
if (match) {
  let area = match[1];
  let country = match[2];
  console.log("Area code is: " + area);
  console.log("Country code is: " + country);
}
else {
  console.log("Invalid phone number.")
}
```